# JMeter 5.4.3 "Generate Paranet Sample" is not working in Non GUI test

Tags: jmeter

I like to generate HTML report with parents transactions only not with all child sample in JMeter 5.4.3
I checked the box "Generate Parent Sample" in transaction controller. But when I execute non gui test from command I see all child sample are included.

Can some help?

Thanks

Saleem Soomro

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a bug in JMeter (at least since JMeter 5.0) so you can raise it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html).

If you don't want to see these "extra" results in the HTML Dashboard the options are in:

1. Downgrade to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) where Transaction Controller still works according to [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) which states:

   > In parent mode, the individual samples can still be seen in the Tree View Listener, but no longer appear as separate entries in other Listeners. Also, the sub-samples do not appear in CSV log files, but they can be saved to XML files
2. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

   this way you will have only "parent" sample results in the .jtl results file (it may have some negative side effect resulting in improper calculation of the throughput when it comes to i.e. embedded resources)

Comment: Even in newer version of JMeter 5.5 Generate parent sample is not working in non gui test.

Can someone provide solution?


Saleem Soomro

Comment: You have been given 3 solutions, what else do you want?